# Using multiple web projects with different languages in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, ide

I need to combine a VB web project and a C# web project and have them run alongside each other in the same web root.  For instance, I need to be able to navigate to `localhost:1234/vbProjPage.aspx` and then redirect to `localhost:1234/cSharpProjPage.aspx`.  Is this possible from within Visual Studio 2008?

I know you have the ability to create a web site and throw everything into the root, but it would be best in this scenario to keep each project separate from each other.

UPDATE: To answer Wes' question, it is possible but not desirable to change paths like that (`/vb/vbPage.aspx` & `/cs/csPage.aspx`)

UPDATE: Travis suggested using sub-web projects. This [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2006/07/01/652986.aspx) explains how to do it  but the solution involves putting a project inside of a project, that is exactly what I am trying to avoid. I need the projects physically separated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using sub-web projects. This has been available in Visual Studio since 2005 and works with the Web Application Project style of web site. [ScottGu has a great blog entry describing the process.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/08/16/tip_2f00_trick_3a00_-creating-sub_2d00_web-projects-using-the-vs-2005-web-application-project-option.aspx) You may face some interesting challenges getting pages to commingle in the same folder, but the sub-web project structure should still lend you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to have two seperate projects but intermixing them within one project isn't a problem. You could always organize the files into folder to keep things seperate if you felt the need.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, would changing your url paths be out of the question?  Instead of 1234/vbpage and 1234/cspage  how about something like 1234/vb/page and 1234/cs/page ?  I know you said same web root, but I'm just curious :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use URL re-writting with a filter to look for "cs" or "vb" at the begining of each file and direct it to the appropriate directory.